# Using data from C# DataReceived thread in a parent class (NO UI, can't Invoke)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class that needs to have properties updated with data from the C# serial DataReceived event.

I'm not trying to update a UI, but the only references I find about using the results of the DataReceived event (which runs on a different thread) say to use .Invoke to get the data into a UI control.  My class is not associated with a UI so .Invoke is not available.

When the handler tries to change a property in the class, I get the dreaded error: *"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."*

What is process for getting the results into the parent thread?

Comment: You say you want to "get the data into a UI control" and then "I don't have a UI control". So which one is it?

Comment: Try this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application

Comment: Brian - I do not want to use UI, I'm just saying that all the references I find only use the UI .Invoke.  I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Are you purchance using Wpf and trying to update a dependency property?

Comment: Although I am not able to put together what you are trying to say but if you don't want to provide UI reference all the way up to DAL then you can take this approach[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I]. Please ignore the comment if it is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to provide UI reference all the way up to DAL then you can take this approach using the [SynchronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I).

Comment: Thank you @MChicago.  that was what I needed to move ahead with the project.